# Count same column twice based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have the following query to count the Amount field as Countused if Account_Fkey is not null

```
select Amount as amount2, Count(Amount) as CountUsed  from tblGiftCards
where Account_Fkey is not null
group by Amount
```

result:

```
amount2 CountUsed   
25      3
50      10
100     5
```

i want to calculate the amount of Amount as Amount not used in the same query where account fkey is null. So, the result will be:

```
amount2 CountUsed CountUnused   
25      3         1
50      10        0
100     5         2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a conditional aggregation

```
select Amount as amount2
    , sum( case when  Account_Fkey is not null 
            and Amount is not null then 1 else 0 end)  CountUsed  
    , sum( case when  Account_Fkey is null 
            and Amount is not null then 1 else 0 end)  CountNotUsed  
    from tblGiftCards
group by Amount
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select tab.amount2 , CountUsed , CountUnUsed   from 
(select Amount as amount2, Count(Amount) as CountUsed  from tblGiftCards
where Account_Fkey is not null
group by Amount 
) tab, 
(select Amount as amount2, Count(Amount) as CountUnUsed  from tblGiftCards
where Account_Fkey is null
group by Amount 
)tab2
where tab.amount2 = tab2.amount2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify the logic and express this as:

```
select Amount as amount2, count(Account_Fkey) as CountUsed,
       (count(*) - count(Account_Fkey)) as CountNotUsed
from tblGiftCards
where Amount is not null
group by Amount
```